# "No component selected." problem in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am newbie developing Android applications with Intellij IDEA. But I have a little problem. When I click on a component from Component Tree, the window that will change its "attributes" does not open. The error I got: "*No component selected.*" Why could it be? I downloaded Gradle again. But I couldn't solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Try to uninstall the current IDE installation and download the 2020.1 version from our [website](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac). Make sure that Gradle has built the project correctly before opening the Layout Editor window.

If the problem remains even in 2020.1 version please file a bug in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA), attach the [log folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) and a sample project.

Comment: Already latest version but the problem persists. Thanks, i will send.

Comment: I have using the android studio for a long time and it's okay. I switched to Intellij and to notice on the right bottom corner exclamation mark. The problem about PATH. The SDK was not in PATH directory(appdata->local->android->sdk), so the settings sdk directory and PATH sdk directory was different. I changed the appdata PATH directory to the real(my installed sdk directory) sdk directory. Now working nice. 

I want report a oddity. I chose the my sdk location in settings but this still looking for sdk in PATH, why?

My english is bad but i hope i explained.